# How to query status of PayPal transactions by URL

Tags: php, xml, paypal

Is there any way to return information of a transaction by transaction id in PayPal?

**Example** ([API](https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/guia-de-integracao/consulta-de-transacoes-por-codigo.html)): https://ws.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/transactions/281AC601-59B6-40CC-ACFC-62B0CD047B14?email=suporte.nfx@gmail.com&token=CDDDA83D856E49CFB5E29C9B376F4CED

**The most we could find was something like this:** paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_view-a-trans&id=7DJ47958EX567045P

This is exactly what I want, but I need in XML.

If it is not possible to display the information in XML, is there any way to get the information with PHP?

Comment: Please don't use URL shortener services.  Your question should be self-contained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the GetTransactionDetails API to obtain details about a transaction.  My [PHP class library for PayPal](https://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/) will make this very simple for you.

The class returns a general PHP array as the result, so if you need XML you could use an array to XML class or something like that.

Alternatively, you could build your own API requests directly to [PayPal's SOAP service](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_SOAP/) instead.

Comment: I am using codeigniter . Any idea how to quickly in Place or have to use the method of third_party addon? I will test here, thanks by reply.

Comment: I actually have a [CodeIgniter specific version of my library](https://www.angelleye.com/product/php-codeigniter-class-library-for-paypal/) you can check out.  I am no longer maintaining that one, though, because the primary one I linked you to is compatible with Composer, so you could install it that way and it would be available within CodeIgniter.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  That library has all of the PayPal classic APIs included with it, so you can easily integrate pretty much anything you need to do with PayPal.